# How to clear an interval in a constant object?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

i'm trying to clear the interval in the `slide.autoplay` function in the following piece of JS.

I wish use another function in my constant like a `slide.stop` function

```
slide = {
    init: () => {
        eraser.content()
        slide.autoplay()
    },
    next: () => {
        eraser.start()
        currentSlide < 1 ? currentSlide++ : currentSlide = 0
        eraser.content()
        eraser.end()
    },
    autoplay: () => setInterval(slide.next, 5000)
}

addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', slide.init )
addEventListener( 'click', slide.stop )
```

*By the way, i'm using functions in constants from a few days now, i found it proper, i don't know if it's a good practice, what are you thinking about it ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the interval before being able to clear it:

```
slide = {
  interval: null,
  init: () => {
    eraser.content()
    slide.autoplay()
  },
  next: () => {
    eraser.start()
    currentSlide < 1 ? currentSlide++ : currentSlide = 0
    eraser.content()
    eraser.end()
  },
  autoplay() {
    this.interval = setInterval(slide.next, 5000)
  },

  stop() {
    if (this.interval) {
      clearInterval(this.interval)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks you ! By the way, why use function instead of arrow keys in this case ?

Comment: Actually in this case both versions should work, but normally functions have to be used to ensure proper binding of `this`. I recommend reading MDN docs for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. In a nutshell, arrow functions set `this` depending on where they are defined 9lexical scope), for other functions it's set depending where it's called.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the id `setInterval` returns.

```
const slide = {
    interval: null,
    play() {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.next, 1000);
    },
    next() {
        console.log("Next");
    },
    stop() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
};
```